# Microsoft Graph Search Filter String in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

The request below works with a triple escape character but not with a single Escape character so if i had the following:

```
string filter = "\"category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\""
```

The string printed for above would give us:

```
filter = "category <> "Person" AND category <> "Person 2""
```

This will not work but the below definition for filter will work:

```
string filter =
    "\"category <> \\\"Person\\\" AND category <> \\\"Person2\\\"\"";

List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("$search", filter)
};

var messages = graphClient.Me
    .MailFolders
    .Inbox
    .Messages
    .Request(options)
    .Select("id, Categories, Subject")
    .Top(500)
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

This filter printed gives us:

```
filter = "category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\""
```

Why do we include a \ in our printed string for the API call? Can someone explain this please?

If \ was an escape character in Microsoft Graph then that would make sense but the escape character in Graph is another ".

Answer (score 2):

Lets start here.

`new QueryOption("$search", filter)`

What we're doing here is preparing a `$search` filter that's going to be appended onto the GET parameters of a url... something like this.

https://...endpoint?$search=filter

If there was no escaping in the final string... it would look like this

https://...endpoint?$search=category <> Person AND category <> Person 2

That's not very good. we need double quotes around out strings

https://...endpoint?$search=category <> "Person" AND category <> "Person 2"

Better, but we want quotes around our entire filter

https://...endpoint?$search="category <> "Person" AND category <> "Person 2""

Doh! Now our filter contains double quotes at the start and end, as well as double quotes around nested strings. ok, lets escape the inner double quotes.

https://...endpoint?$search="category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\""

So now we know we need to build up this string.

"category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\""

well in C# we have a couple of choices... we can either use a normal string, which means we'll need to escape ever `\` and `"`

```
var x = "\"category <> \\\"Person\\\" AND category <> \\\"Person 2\\\"";
```

Alternatively you could use a Verbatim string. It'll cut down on the amount of escaping as you won't need to escape the slashes. In a verbatim string a double quote is escaped as 2 double consecutive double quotes

```
var y = @"""category <> \""Person\"" AND category <> \""Person 2\""";
```

Comment: Thanks Eoin, is this the final url sent to the request?

"category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\"" ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Uri.EscapeDataString() method to escape the string in URL friendly characters?

```
var filter = Uri.EscapeDataString($"\"category <> \"Person\" AND category <> \"Person 2\"");
```

Which turns that string into:

```
%22category%20%3C%3E%20%22Person%22%20AND%20category%20%3C%3E%20%22Person%202%22
```